# Using the calibrate function in rms package for Cox model: use 'hare' method or 'KM'?

Tags: r, regression, survival, cox-model, calibration

I'm creating a calibration plot for my breast cancer prognostic Cox model, which doesn't include any fancy transformations, using the `calibrate()` function in the `rms` package for `R`.  Should I use the `hare` method or `KM`?  Similar literature to what I'm doing always uses the `KM` method, but I'm curious if `hare` is more advantageous.

There are 3 options I have: use the `KM` method, use the `hare` method, or plot both `hare` and `KM` on one figure.

Here's sample code:

```
library(rms)
library(survival)
library(mice)

remove(veteran)
data(veteran)
veteran$trt=factor(veteran$trt,levels=c(1,2))
veteran$prior=factor(veteran$prior,levels=c(0,10))
survmod=with(veteran,Surv(time,status))
fit=cph(survmod~celltype+karno,data=veteran,surv=TRUE,u=100,x=T,y=T)
cal.KM <- calibrate(fit, u=100, cmethod='KM', m=20, B=20)
cal.hare=calibrate(fit,u=100,cmethod='hare',B=20)
plot(cal.hare)
plot(cal.KM,add=TRUE)
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sorry I didn't see this question when you first posed it.

Any method that requires binning of continuous variables is to be avoided.  The often-used method of stratifying predicted values and then computing ordinary Kaplan-Meier estimates was always problematic - you could see this by how noisy the results appeared.  I never use calibration methods based on binning/categorization any more.  `hare` has more precision because it effectively uses interpolation across levels of predicted values, unlike stratification.